# Can't log out on button click on my android app

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

i made an app using java language, Retrofit2 and REST API for server side. in me API class i have login and register parameters like

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    void login(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password, Callback<LoginResult> cb);

    public static class LoginResult
    {
        public int status;
        public String user_api_hash;
    }

    @GET("/registration_status")
    void registrationStatus(@Query("lang") String lang, Callback<RegistrationStatusResult> cb);

    public static class RegistrationStatusResult
    {
        public int status;
    }
    @GET("/get_user_data")
    void getMyAccountData(@Query("user_api_hash") String user_api_hash, @Query("lang") String lang, Callback<GetMyAccountDataResult> cb);

    public static class GetMyAccountDataResult
    {
        public String email, expiration_date, plan;
        public int days_left, devices_limit;
    }
```

my login class is working properly i can login and register any time. when logged in i receive api_kay then it's saved and use in all the app for requests `DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("api_key", loginResult.user_api_hash);` my loginActivity looks like :

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "EditObjectActivity";
    @Bind(R.id.username)
    EditText username;
    @Bind(R.id.password)
    EditText password;
    @Bind(R.id.signin)
    Button signin;
    @Bind(R.id.register)
    Button pwreset;
    private String UrlPrefix;
    private String customServerAddress="https://voila_voila_mon_url.com/";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(activeNetwork == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NoInternetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
        pwreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        username = findViewById(R.id.username);


        String ip = getResources().getString(R.string.ip);
        String httpsOn = getResources().getString(R.string.https_on);

        String server_base = customServerAddress;

        DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("server_base", server_base);
        DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("server", server_base + "api/");

        if (ip.isEmpty()) {
            enableRegistration();
        }
        else {
            API.getApiInterface(LoginActivity.this).registrationStatus("en", new Callback<ApiInterface.RegistrationStatusResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void success(ApiInterface.RegistrationStatusResult result, Response response)
                {
                    if (result.status == 1) {
                        enableRegistration();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failure: retrofitError" + retrofitError.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.errorHappened), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(customServerAddress != null) {
                    String server_base = customServerAddress;
                        server_base = UrlPrefix + server_base;
                    DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("server_base", server_base);
                    DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("server", server_base + "api/");
                }
                API.getApiInterface(LoginActivity.this).login(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), new Callback<ApiInterface.LoginResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void success(ApiInterface.LoginResult loginResult, Response response)
                    {   // progress dialogue
                        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                        progressDialog.setMessage("En cours..."); // Setting Message
                        progressDialog.setTitle("Connexion au serveur"); // Setting Title
                        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER); // Progress Dialog Style Spinner
                        progressDialog.show(); // Display Progress Dialog
                        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }).start();
                        //end progress dialogue

                        DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("api_key", loginResult.user_api_hash);
                        Log.d("LoginActivity", "api_key: " + loginResult.user_api_hash);
                        if(customServerAddress == null)
                        {
                            String url = "https://voila_voila_mon_url.com/";
                            DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("server_base", url);
                            DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("server", url + "api/");
                        }

                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.wrongLogin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }

   
}
```

now the thing is i'd look to log out in my mean activity. in my reseachs i have been told that once logged out the api_key in `DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("api_key", loginResult.user_api_hash);` should be null like **api_key =null**.also when i open the app it show that i am logged. i want to log out.here is my example on **my_logout** button i did this :

```
disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              String log_out = null;
            if(DataSaver.getInstance(this).load("api_key") != null){
               DataSaver.getInstance(this).load("api_key") == log_out;
              finish();
            }else{
             //Toast.......(Toast with message ->>>>unable to log out).
            }
        });
```

This `DataSaver.getInstance(this).load("api_key")` is used in all the app when requesting for GET method when fetching users datas. the api_key saved in the app allow me to make some requests as said before. but when this is null it's impossible to make requests. i want to destroy the session when logged in by loggin out. if you understand what i say and can help please.

my account activity after logged in

```
public class MyAccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Bind(R.id.back) View back;
    @Bind(R.id.expandable_list) ExpandableListView expandable_list;

    @Bind(R.id.loading_layout) View loading_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        loading_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        API.getApiInterface(this).getMyAccountData((String) DataSaver.getInstance(this).load("api_key"), getResources().getString(R.string.lang), new Callback<ApiInterface.GetMyAccountDataResult>() {
            @Override
            public void success(ApiInterface.GetMyAccountDataResult dataResult, Response response)
            {
                MyAccountAdapter adapter = new MyAccountAdapter(MyAccountActivity.this, dataResult);
                expandable_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                Utils.setGroupClickListenerToNotify(expandable_list, adapter);

                loading_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                expandable_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                Toast.makeText(MyAccountActivity.this, R.string.errorHappened, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: In your launching activity(first screen) you have to check your api_key is null or not if it is null then start login screen else your main screen. I hope it will help you

Comment: `DataSaver.getInstance(this).load("api_key") == log_out;`, this expression just compares two values, not assign `log_out` value. From your code, you might call `DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("api_key", log_out);` to make the `"api_key"` `null`.

Answer (score 0):

i did this but it's not enough to log out @Syed Ibrahim
like this
but not working this is juste to stay connected not to log out

```
if (DataSaver.getInstance(this).load("api_key") == null) 
{
            startActivity(new Intent(MapActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        }
```

what i need is to set this api_key null whatever the app is running or not.

Comment: solution found :    disconnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            (DataSaver.getInstance(this).save("api_key", null);         
        });

Comment: @iroiroys thank you for your help this should be DataSaver.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).save("api_key", log_out); in onClickListener with log_out == null; as it's a boolean.